# Change font size Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, attributes, backbone-views, attr

i've got this toolbar made with backbone: http://take.ms/3tYhM

backbone.view:

```
define([
'View/Popup',
'text!Templates/Toolbar/Edit.tpl'
   ], function(Popup, _edit){
    var Edit = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'svs-cke',
    events:{
        'mousedown':                'mousedown',
        'click .bold':              'toggleBold',
        'click .italic':            'toggleItalic',
        'click .underline':         'toggleUnderline',
        'click .link':              'toggleLink',
        'keypress [name="link"]':   'setUrl'
    },

    initialize: function(){

    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.append(_.template(_edit).apply(this.options));
        return this.$el;
    },

    mousedown: function(e){
        if(e.target !== this.$el.find('[name="link"]').get(0)){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    toggleBold: function(e){
        document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleItalic: function(e){
        document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleUnderline: function(e){
        document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('t-active');
    },

    toggleLink: function(e){
        if(this.options.nodes.url){
            this.$el.find('[name="link"]').val(this.options.nodes.url);
        }

        this.lastRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        this.$el.find('[name="link"]').show();
        this.$el.find('[name="link"]').focus();
    },

    setUrl: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.find('[name="link"]').blur();
            window.getSelection().addRange(this.lastRange);
            var url = $(e.currentTarget).val();
            if(url.length > 0){
                document.execCommand('createLink', false, url);
            }else{
                document.execCommand('unlink', false, null);
            }

            $(e.currentTarget).hide();
            this.$el.find('.link').toggleClass('t-active');
        }
    }
});

return Edit;
});
```

i need to add one more button: 'change font-size' what work with my attributes. How i can do this with more elegant and simple way? trying to do this about 4 days :(

add in toolbar.tpl:

```
<div class="size"><div size-class="bigger"></i></div>
```

add new function for change sizes in backbone.view:

```
sizeSelect: function(e){
        $(e.currentTarget).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('selected');

        var size = this.$el.find('.size.selected')
        if(size.length){
            $('[svs-size]').attr('class', size.find('div').attr('size-class'));
            $('[svs-size]').trigger('sizeChange');
        }

    }
```

add event to save model:

```
        el.bind("sizeChange", function(){
        var section = el.parents('section');
        var index   = section.index();
        var model   = collection.at(index);
        model.set(Helper.sectionToObj(section))
    });
```

And my html:

```
<div svs-size class="smaller"></div>
```

but this is doesn't work for me. what i'm doing wrong? BIG thx!

Comment: Did you add the event selector to the events object? I don't see it in your View at the top.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `$('[svs-size]).attr('class', size.find('div').attr('size-class'));` and `$('[svs-size]).trigger('sizeChange');` need to close the quotes on `$('[svs-size])`

Comment: @Deryck thanks, but this is typo, sorry, is not the solution

Comment: I know that's why it's a comment lol